# Sumproduct - counting equal pairs of numbers (and filtering them)

Tags: excel, filtering, sumproduct

In columns D&E I have a list of scores for a game, where D is points for and E is points against, like so

```
D    E
1    3
4    2
3    3
3    1
```

I'm trying to create a formula that displays a win / draw / loss record based on whether column D is larger, equal to or smaller than column E. In this example it would display `2 / 1 / 1`.

So far I have this

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(--(D12:D200>E12:E200)))&" / "&SUMPRODUCT(--(D12:D200=E12:E200))&" / "&(SUMPRODUCT(--(D12:D200<E12:E200)))
```

But there are two issues. One is that all the blank rows are being counted as equals, so the result is coming out as `2 / 186 / 1`.

The second is that in another column I have a list of days of the week, and I would like to be able to filter out rows by day and have the results reflect this. I have different formulas using `SUBTOTAL` instead of `SUM` to count overall number of points, which works fine. But I don't know what the equivalent change I need to make would be for my formula. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first issue, your formula indeed takes blanks into account and treats them as equals. You can adjust your middle `SUMPRODUCT` formula to omit the blanks, just like that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(D12:D200)*(--(D12:D200=E12:E200)))
```

[image]

The second question is regarding filtering out rows by the day of the week. Here's the view before "Day" filter is applied - as you can see we have 5 wins (blue), 4 draws (orange) and 3 losses (green).

[image]

You need to use the following formula to make `SUMPRODUCT` dynamic (i.e. it will react to filtering out rows):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(F12:F200,ROW(F12:F200)-ROW(F12),,1)),--(D12:D200>E12:E200))&" / "&SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(F12:F200,ROW(F12:F200)-ROW(F12),,1)),ISNUMBER(D12:D200)*(--(D12:D200=E12:E200)))&" / "&SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(F12:F200,ROW(F12:F200)-ROW(F12),,1)),--(D12:D200<E12:E200))
```

Here's the result just for Monday:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Both work perfectly - the only issue is I wanted to be able to filter the days by filtering out the column, not by having different formulas for each day. Do you know if this is achievable?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Not sure what you mean by "filtering out the column" - is it possible for you to attach a screenshot along with the expected result?

Comment: Sorry I meant filtering out the rows, not columns. [Like so](https://imgur.com/sn69DSE)

Comment: Ahh I think I know what you mean. If you want your `SUBTOTAL` formula to ignore hidden rows (i.e. those affected by filtering), you can use `=SUBTOTAL(109,range)`. Here's the description: "The Excel SUBTOTAL function with function_num 101-111 neglects values in hidden rows, but not in hidden columns."

Comment: Sorry I'm not explaining myself very well I don't think. What I meant was, I know that  `SUBTOTAL` exists to sum rows with filtered out data, but I'm wondering if there is a way to amend my initial `SUMPRODUCT` formula, maybe using the `SUBTOTAL` command in there or something, so that the formula I posted also doesn't include filtered out rows.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, I think I understand what's happening in that formula to make it work. I noticed that as you've written it, it seems to be reliant on there being data in row F as well, which has none in my example. For mine I switched it to C by updating the formula to `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(C12:C200,ROW(C12:C200)-ROW(C12),,-1)),--(D12:D200>E12:E200))`. Thanks very much for all the help, very insightful.

Comment: No problem at all & glad it worked for you! Feel free to mark my answer as correct in order to close the topic. All the best.